# How to extract a Vector from a Row using PySpark

Tags: python, hash, pyspark

I am trying to run logistic regression on sample data with PySpark. Facing problem on applying 'LabeledPoint' after hashing.

Input data frame:

```
+--+--------+
|C1|      C2|
+--+--------+
| 0|776ce399|
| 0|3486227d|
| 0|e5ba7672|
| 1|3486227d|
| 0|e5ba7672|
+--+--------+
```

After applying hashing on column C2,

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="C2", outputCol="words")
wordsData = tokenizer.transform(df)
hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol="words", outputCol="rawFeatures", numFeatures=20)
featurizedData = hashingTF.transform(wordsData)
idf = IDF(inputCol="rawFeatures", outputCol="features")
idfModel = idf.fit(featurizedData)
rescaledData = idfModel.transform(featurizedData)



+--+--------+--------------------+---------------+--------------------+
|C1|      C2|               words|    rawFeatures|            features|
+--+--------+--------------------+---------------+--------------------+
| 0|776ce399|ArrayBuffer(776ce...|(20,[15],[1.0])|(20,[15],[2.30003...|
| 0|3486227d|ArrayBuffer(34862...| (20,[0],[1.0])|(20,[0],[2.455603...|
| 0|e5ba7672|ArrayBuffer(e5ba7...| (20,[9],[1.0])|(20,[9],[0.660549...|
| 1|3486227d|ArrayBuffer(34862...| (20,[0],[1.0])|(20,[0],[2.455603...|
| 0|e5ba7672|ArrayBuffer(e5ba7...| (20,[9],[1.0])|(20,[9],[0.660549...|
+--+--------+--------------------+---------------+--------------------+
```

now to apply logistic regression, when i perform LabeledPoint

`temp = rescaledData.map(lambda line: LabeledPoint(line[0],line[4]))`

getting following error,

`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for suggestion zero323.

Implemented using pipeline concept.

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
from pyspark.ml.feature import HashingTF, Tokenizer, IDF
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType



dfWithLabel = df.withColumn("label", col("C1").cast(DoubleType()))
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="C2", outputCol="D2")
hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol=tokenizer.getOutputCol(), outputCol="E2")
idf = IDF(inputCol=hashingTF.getOutputCol(), outputCol="features")
lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=10, regParam=0.01)
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[tokenizer, hashingTF,idf,lr])

# Fit the pipeline to training documents.
model = pipeline.fit(dfWithLabel)
```